# Axis2 vs Apache Cxf -- Soap Webservice Client

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I have to communicate with a Soap Webservice and currently I am consuming it through a client built using the Java library Axis2, and everything is going well, but I need to migrate this client for Apache CXF because we have other clients through Apache CXF and when we have Axis2 and Apache Cxf in the same classpath we have some conflicts because of different implementations of XmlSchema that both libraries use.

The problem is when using Apache Cxf the response are being sent in html and not soap as you can see through this stacktrace we are receiving:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: <html>
...
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
...
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor.handleMessage(StaxInInterceptor.java:84)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:835)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1614)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1504)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1310)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:628)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
.. 27 more
```

I have inspected both request and both seem the same as you can see here:

#### Axis 2 Request

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <axis2ns10:login xmlns:axis2ns10="http://auth.smssp.atech.br">LOGIN</axis2ns10:login>
        <axis2ns11:password xmlns:axis2ns11="http://auth.smssp.atech.br">PASSWORD</axis2ns11:password>
        <axis2ns12:sistema xmlns:axis2ns12="http://auth.smssp.atech.br">SYSTEM</axis2ns12:sistema>
    </soapenv:Header>   
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ser:pesquisar xmlns:ns2="http://service.smssp.atech.br">
         <ser:numeroCNS>11111111</ser:numeroCNS>
         <ser:carregarObjetoCompleto>true</ser:carregarObjetoCompleto>
      </ser:pesquisar>
   </soapenv:Body>  
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

#### Apache CXF Request

```xml
<soap:Envelope
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Header>
            <login xmlns="http://auth.smssp.atech.br">LOGIN</login>
            <password xmlns="http://auth.smssp.atech.br">PASSWORD</password>
            <sistema xmlns="http://auth.smssp.atech.br">SYSTEM</sistema>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body> 
            <ns2:pesquisar xmlns="http://domain.smssp.atech.br/xsd" xmlns:ns2="http://service.smssp.atech.br" xmlns:ns3="http://searchFilter.infra.smssp.atech.br/xsd">
            <ns2:numeroCNS>11111111</ns2:numeroCNS>
            <ns2:carregarObjetoCompleto>true</ns2:carregarObjetoCompleto>
        </ns2:pesquisar>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any idea what the problem can be?

Best Regards,
João

Comment: Sorry! 

You can ignore this question. It was my mistake, i was with some issues passing the endpoint of the Web Service. This was creating different endpoints for the different implementations.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Will you please help me.. how did you find the same..i am also facing this issue but not able to find the root cause. just want to Ad when I am testing my webservice on http it works fine but when I use https I am facing this issue.